# Angular Storybook - .storybook only inside lib folder

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm using [Angular Multi Project File Structure](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-project-file-structure), and my goal is to have .storybook only in the lib folder without having it in the root of the workspace.
I manage to set it up, and it compiles and shows the components but I'm receiving these warnings:

```
WARN Your Storybook startup uses a solution that will not be supported in version 7.0.
WARN You must use angular builder to have an explicit configuration on the project used in angular.json
WARN Read more at:
WARN - https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#sb-angular-builder)
WARN - https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#angular13)
ERR! => Could not find angular workspace config (angular.json) on this path "/path_to_the_workspace/projects/lib"
info => Fail to load angular-cli config. Using base config
```

As you can see, there is one ERR where angular.json couldn't be found, which is expected because there is no angular.json inside the library.

I'm quite stuck on this one, and can't find a way around it, so I'd greatly appreciate any inputs :)